# How to override precedence in SQL*Plus?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

```
select * from tab1
minus
select * from tab2
union
select * from tab2
minus
select * from tab1
```

How can I make sure that it is parsed as this?

```
((select * from tab1
minus
select * from tab2)
union
(select * from tab2
minus
select * from tab1))
```

Comment: Symmetric difference?  Do your tables have primary keys?

Comment: yes, they have primary keys, @Jonathan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use your parenthesized expression in the FROM clause, like so?

```
SELECT *
FROM ((select * from tab1 minus select * from tab2)
      UNION
      (select * from tab2 minus select * from tab1)) AS symdiff
```

<s>If the tables have primary keys on the equivalent columns, you may be able to use:</s>

```
SELECT tab1.*
  FROM tab1
 WHERE tab1.pk NOT IN (SELECT tab2.pk FROM tab2)
UNION -- optionally UNION ALL
SELECT tab2.*
  FROM tab2
 WHERE tab2.pk NOT IN (SELECT tab1.pk FROM tab2)
```

However, that is struck out because there is nothing that stops table tab1(pk, othercol) having a row (pk = 1, othercol = 2) while tab2(pk, othercol) contains a row (pk = 1, othercol = 3).  This is something you have to be careful of - I've been caught by the bad assumption once before.

Comment: It gives the sub-query a name - and is nominally required by the SQL standard.  Otherwise, it puzzles the hapless questioner?  I could - maybe should - have written 'SELECT symdiff.* ...'.